# Olingo code failing OData Validator

Tags: odata, olingo

I am new to OData/Olingo. I am trying out the tutorial at Olingo (http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/read/tutorial_read.html), and have currently completed chapter 2. However, When I tried validating my service through the OData Validator (http://services.odata.org/validation/) it fails stating:         `Error retrieving validation results`

Here is what I get when I hit: /ODataDemo/Service.svc/

```
<app:service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" metadata:context="$metadata">
  <app:workspace>
   <atom:title>NTTD.OData.Container</atom:title>
   <app:collection href="Properties">
    <atom:title>Properties</atom:title>
   </app:collection>
  </app:workspace>
</app:service>
```

Here is the metadata at /ODataDemo/NttdService.svc/$metadata

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="NTTD.OData">
            <EntityType Name="Property">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="Location" Type="Edm.String"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer Name="Container">
                <EntitySet Name="Properties" EntityType="NTTD.OData.Property"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Please help. Where are things going wrong?

Comment: I tried testing the code with the ODataAPI Explorer (http://services.odata.org/ODataAPIExplorer/ODataAPIExplorer.html) and here is the error I receive:

Comment: `{"message":"HTTP request failed","request":{"requestUri":"http://xxxx:8080/ODataDemo/NttdService.svc/$metadata","recognizeDates":false,"callbackParameterName":"$callback","formatQueryString":"$format=json","enableJsonpCallback":false,"inferJsonLightFeedAsObject":false,"method":"GET","headers":{"Accept":"application/xml","MaxDataServiceVersion":"3.0"}},"response":{"requestUri":"http://xxxx:8080/ODataDemo/NttdService.svc/$metadata","statusCode":0,"statusText":"","headers":[],"body":""}}`